# MVC 4 - View That Accepts Multiple Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, parameters

I have seen a few other threads with the same question as mine but I don't understand them very much. Anyway, my scenario is this: I have a MainView which renders four different PartialViews in it. The reason is because each PartialView contains data that comes from different Tables(Models).

So my problem is this. My MainView accepts a parameter of type string which is an ID. I need to pass that ID to each of my PartialViews. This can be easily achieved but the problem is, each partial views also needs to accept parameter of type List<>.

My question is, how can I pass two parameters to my PartialView (ie string and List<>)?

Currently, my PartialViews accept only one parameter (List<>).

Answer (score 1):

create an object containing both the string and the list<>, and pass that to your PartialViews.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModels. Create a Viewmodel that is the result of all objects you need to present in the view. Is more clean.

There are many articles with this information.

Comment: It would be better if you included some links to the articles you are referring to.